# Python co-occurrence matrix, how to multiply row/column by integer?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a co-occurrence matrix of the following form:

```
       Cat  Dog Zebra
Cat     0    2    3
Dog     2    0    1
Zebra   3    1    0
```

which has been generated with the python pandas library.  Let's say that the its data frame is stored in the variable `df` and I have another integer variable `x`.  Then how could I multiply all values for an animal by my variable `x`?

For example, if my variable x = 2 and animal = Dog, then the matrix would look like this:

```
       Cat  Dog Zebra
Cat     0    4    3
Dog     4    0    2
Zebra   3    2    0
```

Comment: Why isn't `dog, zebra` getting multiplied?

Comment: Patrick Haugh: My bad, I will fix the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To multiply a row:

```
df.loc['Dog', :] = df.loc['Dog', :] * x
```

To multiply a column:

```
df['Dog'] = df['Dog'] * x
```

See this page for more info:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html